# loginButton.registerCallback cannot resolve method

Tags: android, facebook, callback

> Error:(36, 20) error: cannot find symbol method
>   registerCallback(CallbackManager,>)

When i called this registerCallback from my Mainactivity to `facebook sdk 4.0's lib`. Here is my class

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView tv;
        Button loginButton;
        CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("Oncreate", "Now on On create");
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294015/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-with-fb-sdk-4-0-for-android

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I removed the Android part of the title as this is apparent anyway.

Comment: Checking if anyone has another answer here - I am having the same issue, Android Studio is saying that `loginButton.registerCallback` cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext())` **before** `setContentView()`. sample code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginFaceBook_button);
//etc..
```

Also the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android) mentions to *either* use `loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()` **or** `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback (callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()` , not both of them. Here is a full sample code:

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginFaceBook_button);
    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception)
        {
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to include `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`loginButton` must be of type `LoginButton` instead of `Button`.

Unrelated: You do not need to register the callback on both the `loginButton` and `LoginManager.getInstance()`. The former is for the `loginButton` flow, the latter if you have your own button or login trigger. In fact it's not clear on Facebook's documentation, not your fault.