# FB SDK 4.0 for Android: User still logged even the permission was removed?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm creating an app that implements a Facebook Login and i'm having problems with one scenario:

Step#1 - User logs into my app with FB login.
Step#2 - The user removes the permission for my app on FB web.
Step#3 - The user opens my app and **it's still logged**.

According to their docs:

> Your app can only have one person at a time logged in and LoginManager sets the current AccessToken and Profile for that person.
> The FacebookSDK saves this data in shared preferences and sets it during SDK initialization. You can see if a person is already logged in by checking `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` and `Profile.getCurrentProfile()`.

`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` and `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` won't be null because the user logged once.

But if the SDK saves the datas in shared preferences, **i can't figure it out how i will know if the user removed the permission?**

I watched the
[How to check if user is logged in with FB SDK 4.0 for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294015/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-with-fb-sdk-4-0-for-android) but the solution doesn't work because doesn't makes no sense and at least i tried to use it..

Answer (score 0):

If you do a graph call, the SDK will figure out that the permissions are removed/changed and adjust the access token accordingly.